# dropdown menu doesn't stay still after mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am using the veggie theme on Wordpress and have added subcategories to the primary menu, which appear as a dropdown list with mouse hover. However, with mouse out the dropdown disappears. Any ideas on how I can fix it?

The website is http://iceyog.gr/ and the menu element is "FROZEN YOGURT"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a few px of space above the ul element (dropdown).

In the style.css file on line 2207 there is this code:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
background: white;
float: left;
margin-left: -0.875em;
padding: 0 0.875em;
position: absolute;
top: 1.75em; // (Remove this line to fix the issue)
left: -999em;
text-align: left;
width: 180px;
z-index: 99999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the `hover` event is set on the `a` element instead of the `li` element.

Since the `ul` child group is in the `li` element, when you `hover` the `li` you can still see the dropdown when you `hover` it instead of `hover` the `a` element which is not hover when you hover the dropdown child menu.

[Here's a basic example to explain my thoughts](https://jsfiddle.net/5xzdgsdq/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! Well, i understand what is going on, but i don't understand the changes i have to make! I think that  nathan's answer is more deterministic and it helped! Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. It's true, his answer was exactly about the current issue and mine was not this particular case.